# $\overline{C^{\infty}}^{||\cdot||_{\alpha}} \neq C^{\alpha}$; lower bound of $ \frac{|(s-\delta/2)^{\alpha} - s^{\alpha}|}{(\delta/2)^{\alpha}}$

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds, holder-spaces, rough-path-theory

I would like to prove myself that:

$$\overline{C^{\infty}}^{||\cdot||_{\alpha}} \neq C^{\alpha}$$

where the left hand side is the closure with respect to the semi-norm of Holder continuous functions (see below).
The right hand side being $\alpha$-Holder continuous functions, with classical semi-norm:

$$ ||X||_{\alpha} =  \sup \frac{ X_t - X_s } {(t-s)^{\alpha}} $$

During the lecture, the professor mentioned that $X_t = t^{\alpha} $ is a counter example.

I have proven that $t^{\alpha}$ is in $\alpha$-Holder continuous functions.

Now I struggle to prove that the characterisation of the LHS is not respected by $t^{\alpha}$:

$$\lim_{ \delta \to 0} \sup_{ |t-s| < \delta }  \frac{ X_t - X_s } {(t-s)^{\alpha}} = 0 $$

My attempt is to pick $t = s + \delta/2$. Now I would need help to find a lower-bound for:

$$ \frac{|(s-\delta/2)^{\alpha} - s^{\alpha}|}{(\delta/2)^{\alpha}}$$

Comment: Can't you use simply some Taylor expansion? You have the freedom to choose $s$ as well

Comment: @md5 agree, so I took s>0, and wrote $(s- \delta/2)^{\alpha} = s^{\alpha} ( 1 - \delta / (2s))^{\alpha} = s^{\alpha} [ 1 - \alpha \delta / (2 s) + o( \delta / (2s)]$, but I do not see how it helps. Then when I take the limit for $\delta$ to $0$, the fraction converges to $0$ exactly how we do not want it to be. Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: What if you pick $s=\delta$?

Comment: Then the expression indeed converges to infinity at 0, thanks !!